# How to change C++ version of a MinGW compiler

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, mingw-w64

I am trying to compile Qt5.15 from the source and I have the compiler in my PATH and it is being found. However, when I run the configure file in the command prompt, I get the following error: /qt-everywhere-src-5.15.0/qt-everywhere-src-5.15.0/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qfloat16.h:300:7: error: 'numeric_limits' is not a class template
300 | class numeric_limits<QT_PREPEND_NAMESPACE(qfloat16)> : public numeric_limits

I know that this means it's not in the standard library of the C++ version I am using but how can I change this?

I am using Windows 10 and running it through the command prompt.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Uninstall the old compiler. Use MSYS2 compilers and packages with Qt.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-can-i-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-can-i-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2)

Comment: [https://www.msys2.org/#installation](https://www.msys2.org/#installation)

Comment: Install and use a newer compiler.

Comment: I have installed the newest MSYS" compiler but I am still receiving the same error, what could I do now?

Comment: Are you compiling from the mingw64 terminal? I can possibly test that in 10 to 12 hours as I am leaving for work soon and need to do some work in the server room..

Comment: I have just tried from the MSYS2 UCRT64 terminal and it still gives me my original error

Comment: I confirm that it did fail this morning when I tested building qt5.15.10 using msys2 installed MinGW. I don't have enough time at the moment to test and understand the build errors. You may want to check the bug reports for Qt + MinGW.

Comment: ***error: 'numeric_limits' is not a class template*** I believe that this means you need to edit the source file it complains about and add `#include <limits>` at the top. [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) In the past I have had to add a few `#include <>`s for building Qt from source with msvc. I have done that several hundred times for work but only with msvc not MinGW.